# Rails select in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my model `User`, I have scope set up:

```
scope :count_likes, lambda { 
     select("(SELECT count(*) from another_model) AS count") 
}
```

If I want to get all attributes of my User + count_likes, I have to do:

```
Model.count_likes.select("users.*")
```

because calling select() will the default `"*"`

I use `count_likes` scope a lot of my application and my issue is that I have to append select("users.*") everywhere.

I know about the default scope, however, I don't think doing `select("users.*")` in default scope if a good idea.

Is there a DRY / better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really another answer.  I wanted to leave a comment about the joins, but comments cannot run long and I wanted to provide code examples.

What you need is to sometimes get all the fields and counts of a related table, and other times get the counts without the users.* fields, (and maybe sometimes just the user.* fields without the counts). So, you are going to have to tell the code which one you want. I think what you are looking for is an except type of thing, where by default you get the user.* fields and the counts, but when you only want the counts, to specify turning off the select('user.*'). I don't think there is such a solution, except maybe using the default scope. I suggest having one scope for just the counts, and one scope for users fields and the counts.

Here is what I would do:

```
class Users
  has_many :likes

  def self.with_count_likes
    joins(:likes)
      .select('users.*, count(likes.id) as count')
      .group('users.id')
  end

  def self.count_likes
    joins(:likes)
      .select('users.id, users.username, count(likes.id) as count')
      .group('users.id')
  end
...
```

Call with_count_likes (or chain it into a query) when you want all the users fields and the likes counts.  Call count_likes when you want just the counts and a few identifying fields.

I'm assuming here that whenever you want the counts, you want *some* users fields to identify what/(who) the counts are for.

Note that some databases (like Oracle) may require grouping by 'users.*'.  This is the standard in SQL, but some databases like mySQL only use the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply add `users.*` to the scope.

```
scope :count_likes, lambda { 
     select("(SELECT count(*) from another_model) AS count, users.*") 
}
```

HTH

EDIT: I am not sure of exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you should consider using `joins` and get the data by joining tables appropriately.

EDIT: Usually I am not a big fan of making such changes, but as situation suggests sometimes we need to get our hands dirty. In this case, I would try to reduce the number of operations in terms of making changes. Consider:

`scope :count_likes, Proc.new { |all| s = select("(SELECT count(*) from another_model) AS count"); s = s.select("users.*") unless all == false; s` }

Now you will get `users.*` everywhere. For specific places where you just need the  count, you may replace it like `User.count_likes(false)` and it will give you just the counts. Thus minimal changes.

There may be another possibility of appending multiple scopes together, one for counts, one for `users.*` and use them to achieve the above effect.

Comment: No, adding users.* to select in scope is bad because in the scenario I only want count_likes.

Comment: Okay. I answered it because you specified `I have to append select("users.*") everywhere`. Anyways, you can also scope named-scoped as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By everywhere I meant, most of the places where I use count_likes.

Comment: How would you do it in my situation? In other words, you have a Model and almost every time you query, you need to return a count of another model with it, but if you use select(blah blah blah), then you have to add "users.*" everytime.

Comment: Updated my post. Its a rough idea from top of my head, so may not look robust.

Comment: What you need is to sometimes get all the fields and counts of a related table, and other times get the counts without the users.* fields.  So, you are going to have to tell the code which one you want.  I think what you are looking for is an except type of thing, where by default you get the user.* fields and the counts, but when you only want the counts, to specify turning off the select('user.*').  I don't think there is such a solution, except maybe using the default scope.  I suggest having one scope for just the counts, and one scope for users fields and the counts.